# Delete object from opencpu session

Tags: r, apache, opencpu

How do I delete a previously created object in OpenCPU?

I need to delete some unused objects. For example, the result of a POST is the following:

```
/ocpu/tmp/x0b0f8555a1e1d6/R/.val
/ocpu/tmp/x0b0f8555a1e1d6/stdout
/ocpu/tmp/x0b0f8555a1e1d6/source
/ocpu/tmp/x0b0f8555a1e1d6/console
/ocpu/tmp/x0b0f8555a1e1d6/info
/ocpu/tmp/x0b0f8555a1e1d6/files/DESCRIPTION
```

How do I delete the object x0b0f8555a1e1d6?

I tried posting to

```
curl http://myserver:myport/ocpu/library/base/R/rm -d "x0b0f8555a1e1d6"
```

which gives an error:

```
... must contain names or character strings

In call:
rm(x0b0f8555a1e1d6 = NA)
```

And

```
curl http://myserver:myport/ocpu/library/base/R/rm -d "list='x0b0f8555a1e1d6'"
```

gives a warning that the object was not found:

```
object 'x0b0f8555a1e1d6' not found
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow ! Could you please paste the error you had ? So people will better help you with your question.

Comment: sure thanks, I added them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The temporary objects automatically get deleted after a while (usually 24h). There is no http API to manually prune them. Have a look at the `/etc/cron.d/opencpu` script on your server.

If you really want to delete a session you can manually delete the directory in `/tmp/ocpu-store/` on your server. It also gets automatically deleted on reboot.

Comment: Thanks! I think it would be convenient to have an API to manually delete objects. In my use case, there can be some trial and error before the wanted object is created, and all others created previously can be deleted at that point...